Java Springboot Sequence of automatic beans
I integrate Keycloak into my service using the following example.
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-keycloak
This works fine for me.
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri=http://localhost:8080/realms/SpringBootKeycloak
Now I have added an ssl configuration. This should be executed first, so that it also works.
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri=https://localhost:8080/realms/SpringBootKeycloak
But InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository it is always loaded beforehand. How can I influence the sequence here?
I try to register a ClientRegistrationRepository @Bean like this:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/login/core.html
But this requires more parameters than the solution from my example. In addition, I don't want to create a new client registration, but only influence the time at which the automatically generated one is loaded

The Baeldung article you are reading configures an OAuth2 client (with oauth2Login). The parts refering to resource server in it are mostly missleading and unused is the built solution. I suggest that you have a look at my tutorials to have a chance to understand the differences bettween OAuth2 clients VS resource servers, and the very different security considerations between the two (which make it a nonsense to configure the two in a single security filter-chain as done in the article you read).
Spring OAuth2 clients fetch the OpenID configuration eagerly because it tries to auto-configure using the OpenID configuration exposed by the authorization server. Just make sure that your services start order is the right one (authorization server started 1st and Spring OAuth2 clients last). There is no chance that your backend works if the authorization server is down...
Also have a look at this other answer: when using SSL with a self-signed certificate, make sure that the same value is used by:

Keycloak for its hostname
the certificate CN
configured Spring issuer-uri

